# Cacti - Poller stopped after data source template changed - Old but gold

Tags: graph, monitoring, rrdtool, cacti

I'm new here and this is my first post :)

I will try to explain, sorry ahead about my grammar

We moved to GPDR few months ago, and my job is to fix all the graph which Stopped working, we notice it was due to a change in data-source, in this case it was the volume of the disks
Ex: xvdg - xvdf (AWS)

What I've done:
Duplicated each old data source template. to a new one with a new name and volume
Then i changed the old graph with the new data source template

The weird thing that happened, this worked on only 1 graph, and all the other graphs I've change, stopped, didn't show data, 
Checking the Cacti logs
I notice these graph pollers are gone...
5 pollers are not showing anymore in the logs
I've tried:

Deleting the rrd, so it will recreate itself - it did but no poller
Re cached the poller index - didnt do any change
Messing with RDDTOOL

Then i notice that if i create a new graph with the new data sources it will work
But i got 6x20 of these to do, i need a creative better way to do this

Please help
Thanks